# Google App Engine, tasks in Task Queue are not executed automatically

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, task-queue

My tasks are added to Task Queue, but nothing executed automatically. I need to click the button "Run now" to run tasks, tasks are executed without problem. Have I missed some configurations ?

I use default queue configuration, standard App Engine with python 27.

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue

taskqueue.add(
        url='/inserturl',
        params={'name': 'tablename'})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have resolved the problem. Excuse me, I didn't pay attention, in fact, my task queue is paused in console google. I just resume it and all works.

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quickstart-appengine) is for the API you are now mentioning. The idea would be the same: you need to specify the parameter for when you want the task to be executed. In this case, you have different options, such as `countdown` or `eta`. Here is the [specific documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/tasks) for the method you are using to add a task to the queue (`taskqueue.add`)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

If you follow this [tutorial to create queues and tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quickstart-appengine), you will see it is based on the following [github repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/tasks). If you go to the file where the tasks are created (`create_app_engine_queue_task.py`). There is where you should specify the time when the task must be executed. In this tutorial, to finally create the task, they use the following command:

```
python create_app_engine_queue_task.py --project=$PROJECT_ID --location=$LOCATION_ID --queue=$QUEUE_ID --payload=hello
```

However, it is missing the time when you want to execute it, it should look like this

```
python create_app_engine_queue_task.py --project=$PROJECT_ID --location=$LOCATION_ID --queue=$QUEUE_ID --payload=hello --in_seconds=["countdown" for when the task will be executed, in seconds]
```

Basically, the key is in this part of the code in `create_app_engine_queue_task.py`:

```
if in_seconds is not None:
    # Convert "seconds from now" into an rfc3339 datetime string.
    d = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=in_seconds)

    # Create Timestamp protobuf.
    timestamp = timestamp_pb2.Timestamp()
    timestamp.FromDatetime(d)

    # Add the timestamp to the tasks.
    task['schedule_time'] = timestamp
```

If you create the task now and you go to your console, you will see you task will execute and disappear from the queue in the amount of seconds you specified.

Comment: In fact, I use api python taskqueue to create task.

Comment: Please note that when this answer was posted, the OP had not yet disclosed that they were using `taskqueue`. Downvotes are probably premature in this case.